# Как сделать сортировку объектов по дате? ts

Tags: javascript, сортировка, typescript

```
interface Users {
birthday: string;
}
list: Users[];
list: [
  {
    birthday: '1993-08-24',
  },
  {
    birthday: '2019-08-24',
   
  },
  {
    birthday: '2018-08-24',
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      Date.parse(b.birthday) - Date.parse(a.birthday)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

При данном формате даты самый простой вариант:

```js
const list = [
  {
    birthday: '1993-08-24',
  },
  {
    birthday: '2019-08-24',

  },
  {
    birthday: '2018-08-24',
  },
];


const sortList = list.sort((a,b) => {
  return new Date(a.birthday).getTime() - new Date(b.birthday).getTime();
});
console.log(sortList)
```

Comment: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Comment: У меня даже с кривыми датами такой ошибки нет. Покажите ваш код и где ругается

Comment: @SwaD, это ошибка от `typescript` [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gWAFAxgbxzzwCMEAnKACwBMBDATwC4YByARgE5OBmAWgAMADj4AmACysANERgBfGbgKzSFavWZtRAroJETpOWQtmElqyrUYtW29iOFjJivCewBdANxHsOUJFgIEEoAGSRYNERoADogygAKeLopEgBKVAA+ZSVyAFMoAFdyMBgwXIB3GAAROihcpOiySw10vlKK6tr6kka1KwZU72w5VL9wILhc6LgQAHN4uKgw6FSgA)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! Поправил под typeScript

Comment: Теперь твой код не работает :)

Comment: Уже работает ))

Comment: `getTime`  и так `number` возвращает, не нужно типы проверять.